# How to get values from FormArray - Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

SectionService form

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      siteDestinationSectionsList: this.fb.array([this.siteDestinationSectionsListGroup]),
   // removed rest
    });

siteDestinationSectionsListGroup =
     this.fb.group({
      siteCodeId: ['',Validators.required],
      description: [''],
// removed rest
    });
```

component.ts

```
get siteDestinationSectionsListArray() {
    return this.techneSectionForm.get('siteDestinationSectionsList') as FormArray;
  }
```

I try to get the values of `siteDestinationSectionsListArray`

`console.log("siteDestinationSectionsListArray", this.siteDestinationSectionsListArray);`

In console
[image: siteDestinationSectionsListArray]

**I want the value of siteCodeId.
How can I get that?**

I tried with    `console.log("siteDestinationSectionsListArray.value", this.siteDestinationSectionsListArray.value);`
But I got
`[ { "siteCodeId": "",   "description": "", "links": [], "images": [] } ]`
Here siteCodeId is ""
But The  `siteDestinationSectionsListArray` has siteCodeId is 3.
Why I could not get siteCodeId as 3 ?

Answer (score 2):

```
this.siteDestinationSectionsListArray.at(index)
```

and then you can access the field that you want, in your case .siteCodeId

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get it by using the FormArray's `at(index)` method.

`this.siteDestinationSectionsListArray.at(0).value.siteCodeId`